# Script doesn't execute in crontab

Tags: bash, shell, cron, sh

I wanna run a script using crontab in every minute. The script is located at `/Users/robin47/Desktop/script/demo.sh`. As a side note, I give the execute permission of `demo.sh` file with `chmod +x demo.sh` command.

But it doesn't execute the script. Here is the process I'm following:

Run `crontab -e` from the terminal.

```
robin47@mac-pro ~ % crontab -e
```

this open a file(crontab.xxxxxxx) in nano which is located under tmp folder, as an example `File: /tmp/crontab.V4DcXEJU8g`.

This is my `crontab.xxxxxxx` file:

```
SHELL=/bin/bash 
PATH=/bin:/sbin:/usr/bin:/usr/sbin
* * * * * /bin/bash /Users/robin47/Desktop/script/demo.sh
```

[Get from here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20582224/shell-script-not-running-via-crontab-but-runs-fine-manually), this doesn't execute my `demo.sh` script.

If I run sh command from terminal like `sh demo.sh`, it works. And if I directly echo(or run any command like touch, mkdir) in crontab like this

```
SHELL=/bin/bash 
PATH=/bin:/sbin:/usr/bin:/usr/sbin
* * * * * echo 'hello' >> /Users/robin47/Desktop/script/text.txt
```

It also works. But doesn't run the script using crontab. I appreciate your help, Thanks.

This is my `demo.sh` file:

```
#!/bin/sh

echo "hello world" >> /Users/robin47/Desktop/script/text.txt
```

Comment: (1) If you invoke the script in the way you are doing it, setting the x-bit is not necessary. (2) "does not work" is not the best problem description imaginable. Provide some reasonable error description by telling, which statement in the script works differently from what you expect. (3) For debugging, run the script by `bash -x ...../demo.sh`

Comment: Recent versions of macOS restrict access to "personal" data, including anything in the Desktop folder (and a number of other places). See [this question on Ask Different](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/332673/what-and-how-does-macos-mojave-implement-to-restrict-applications-access-to-pers). I'd recommend moving the script and the things it accesses to a non-private area. If that's not possible, you'll need to grant access to cron (see [this question](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/378553/crontab-operation-not-permitted), though it shouldn't need Full Disk Access).

Comment: @GordonDavisson after giving access it works.

Answer (score -2):

refer below site for cron entries , also check your script have executable permission
chmod oug+x  demo.sh

https://crontab.guru/

Comment: script has the executable permission, can you please elaborate your answer what can be problem(s).