# BASH script not running in crontab, but runs manually

Tags: linux, bash, shell, cron

It is necessary to run the bash script with cron from under the current user, but it is not executed when cron is running. I was looking at similar topics on the Internet, and I was unable to find out the reason. Please help me find the root of the problem.

```
admin@user-desktop:~$ crontab -e
SHELL=/bin/bash
PATH=/bin:/sbin:/usr/bin:/usr/sbin
* * * * * sh /usr/bin/local/send_my_ip.sh >/dev/null 2>&1

May 15 20:31:01 user-desktop CRON[408639]: (admin) CMD (sh /usr/bin/local/send_my_ip.sh >/dev/null 2>&1)
May 15 20:37:01 user-desktop CRON[408805]: (admin) CMD (/bin/bash /usr/bin/local/send_my_ip.sh >/dev/null 2>&1)
May 15 20:38:01 user-desktop CRON[408841]: (admin) CMD (/bin/bash /usr/bin/local/send_my_ip.sh >/dev/null 2>&1)

admin@user-desktop:~$ ls -l  /usr/local/bin/send_my_ip.sh
-rwxrwxrwx 1 admin admin 569 may 15 20:27 /usr/local/bin/send_my_ip.sh
 
#!/bin/bash
. ~/.bashrc

MY_IP=$(wget -qO- eth0.me)
MY_IP_LAST=$(cat ~/my_ip.txt)
echo "$MY_IP" >> /home/admin/log_cron.log
```

don't work
[Shell script not running via crontab, but runs fine manually](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20582224/shell-script-not-running-via-crontab-but-runs-fine-manually)

Comment: Try to add: `. ~/.bashrc` after the shebang in your script.

Comment: #!. ~/.bashrc
it didn't help, but the script itself works

Comment: @shaman888 place the `. ~/.bashrc` on a ***separate line after*** the `#!/bin/bash`

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/tags/cron/info for good info on debugging cron problems. I have added the `cron` tag as well to your Q. Good luck.

Comment: I'd have a concern with your crontab entry ... why are you calling the script with `sh` instead of `bash`? on your system is `sh` a copy of (or simlink to) `bash`?

Comment: `sh /usr/bin/local/send_my_ip.sh >/dev/null 2>&1` The `/dev/null` part is currently discarding the output of your script. You should redirect the output of the script to a file so you can see the error message.

Comment: Not related to the problem, but remember to quote all your variables. Paste your code into shellcheck.net to look for other problems.

Comment: `[ $X_1 == '']` is no valid syntax. Please paste your script at [shellcheck.net](http://www.shellcheck.net/) and try to implement the recommendations made there.

Comment: admin@user-desktop:~$ sudo cat /var/log/syslog | grep CRONMay 15 21:20:01 user-desktop CRON[410048]: (admin) CMD (sh /usr/bin/local/send_my_ip.sh )
May 15 21:20:01 user-desktop CRON[410047]: (CRON) info (No MTA installed, discarding output)

Comment: `No MTA installed`: Install and configure a MTA (mail transfer server), e.g. `postfix`.

Comment: That means it generated some output but it could not send it to you because you don't have mail configured. Try writing the output to a file in a directory where you have write access, instead of to `/dev/null`

Comment: @Cyrus I don't need cron to send me anything by email, for this I previously added it to the cron ">/dev/null 2>&1"

Comment: But that's why nobody can tell you what's wrong. We (and you) need to see the error message before this problem can be diagnosed.

Comment: Typo: Surely `/usr/bin/local` should be `/usr/local/bin`?

Comment: Why do you need `. ~/.bashrc` at all? What's in this file?